# Casting with sqlite3

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I do not come from a xcode background, but java and c#.  Now i am trying to change my app to ios and not sure i am understanding how to cast properly, or more to the point, what is xcodes problem!

I am trying to do something very simple, get the values from sqlite and populate a NSMutableDictionary object.

I would like to get values such as long, int and string and it seems i have to do all sorts of casting to get the compiler to like it.  Can someone point me in the right direction as what i should be writing as surely this aint neccessary.

My dictionary variable is called myDictionary for this example.

Add string to NSDictionary

```
[myDictionary setValue:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 4)] forKey:@"myText"];
```

Add int to NSDictionary

```
[myDictionary setValue: [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt:sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0)] forKey:@"myInt" ];
```

Is all this casting really neccessary?  I thought i could do simple things like this

Add int to NSDictionary

```
[myDictionary setValue: sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0) forKey:@"myInt" ];
```

But this saying

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Also tried

```
[myDictionary setValue: (int *)sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0) forKey:@"myInt" ];
```

But i get

> Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

I have tried the same things with text as well.  Someone please let me know if i am not doing this correctly.

Even something like this doesnt work

```
int *myVar = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
```

And if i change it too

```
int myVar = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
```

which does work, then i cannot populate it into NSDictionary as this errors

```
[myDictionary setValue:myVar forKey:@"intValue"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some of the casting is necessary.  A lot of this is that you're mixing sqlite's C interface with Objective C, and you have to observe what is an object and what is a primitive. Your first example (string) is pretty much how it is.  An NSString is a lot different from a char * of C.  Likewise with the NSNumber following it. Notice though, you're only doing one cast and that's from

```
const unsigned char *
```

to

```
char *
```

NSDictionaries should only store objects, not primitives, so you need to put in NSStrings and NSNumbers, instead of char * and int.

You don't want to be plugging pointers to primitives, like (int *) into an NSDictionary, convert them to objects first, then unconvert when you fetch them again.

It might be helpful to you that there are shortcut routines like:

```
[myMutableDictionary setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"mykey"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the shortcut is very helpful.  Much easier when you know these methods exist.  Pitty one doesnt exist for NSString though...or is there?

Comment: Another handy call is [NSString stringWithFormat:@"like printf formats %d %@", an_Integer, an_ObjectiveC_object];